# Ktor native request inteceptor

Tags: native, interceptor, ktor

I need to add a header to requests based on the body. How can I add interceptor for client requests? I have tried

```
 httpClient.requestPipeline.intercept(HttpRequestPipeline.Send) { context: PipelineContext<Any, HttpRequestBuilder> ->
            context.proceed()
}
```

But it wasn't called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `State` phase of the `HttpSendPipeline` to modify request:

```
val client = HttpClient(Apache)

client.sendPipeline.intercept(HttpSendPipeline.State) {
    context.headers.append("myHeader", context.body.toString())
}

val r = client.get<String>("http://httpbin.org/get")
println(r)
```