# How to use existing okhttp3 Interceptor in ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am working in Kotlin Mutliplatorm moblie in android and ios project. When I was using Retrofit, I could easily create interceptors to see the calls:

```
 val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(HeadersInterceptor())
```

Header Interceptor

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class HeadersInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

        requestBuilder.addHeader("Client-Version", getClientVersion())

        val request = requestBuilder.build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    private fun getClientVersion(): String {
        var versionName = BuildConfig.HEADER_VERSION
        return "Android $versionName"
    }
}
```

and then

```
 val retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(httpClient.build())
```

Now I am want to switch [Ktor](https://ktor.io/). My problem is can I reuse **okhttp3** `HeadersInterceptor()` in ktor? if yes, So How can I use please give me example. If no please tell me alternative approach because I have so many Interceptor like AuthorizationInterceptor, own implementation of Interceptor. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ktor native request inteceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763597/ktor-native-request-inteceptor)

Comment: @Jigar no I have so many inteceptor I gave the example of header. My main question is how can I use different interceptor using ktor. for example session, retry api call and many more ...

Comment: Did you thoroughly look at route API of ktor? Everything you're doing with different interceptors might be possible through routes.

- https://ktor.io/docs/intercepting-routes.html
- https://medium.com/@shrikantjagtap99/role-based-authorization-feature-in-ktor-web-framework-in-kotlin-dda88262a86a
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ktor/comments/iqso9k/need_help_running_an_interceptor_on_only_certain/

Comment: @Jigar do I need to rewrite every interceptor logic in thw way of route example? or I can use class. To be honest I am totally confused. I don't know about anything route api in ktor. Thanks

Comment: Answered in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3963.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add your interceptor to Ktor OkHttp client builder

```
val client: HttpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    engine {
        config {
            addInterceptor( YourInterceptor() )
        }
    }
}
```